# extracting frame features for videos using I3D pytorch implementation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, video-processing, feature-extraction

I have a large datasets of videos related to human activities. I have converted the dataset to RGB frames. I want to generate features for these frames from the I3D pytorch architecture. I don't have the flow frames as of now, is it possible to extract features without the flow. Also if anyone can please help me with the process to extract features with I3D. Thank you very much.